# How to add search bar in navigation bar of tabbed page

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigationbar, searchbar, tabbedpage

I am using the xamarin. forms application, where there will be two tabs with a search icon in the navigation bar. What I wanted here to implement is, when the search icon is tapped all the navigation bar and the tabs should disappear and open the search bar with respect to the current tab.

The example: initially, the page will be like as

[image]

when the search icon is tapped, I want the view as follows.

[image]

how can it be achieved?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to write the layout yourself. You can't simply achieve it by shell or naviagtionbar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xamarin's latest [Xamarin.Forms Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/introduction?WT.mc_id=docs-xamarinblog-jamont) to achieve tabbed page kind of Layout.

Refer to following code structure:

**AppShell.Xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
       xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ProjectName.Views"
       x:Class="ProjectName.AppShell">
    <Tab>
        <ShellContent 
                      Title="Page1"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Page1}" />
        <ShellContent 
                      Title="Page2"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Page2}" />
    </Tab>
</Shell>
```

**Page1.Xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="ProjectName.Views.Page1" 
             Title="Page1">

   <Shell.SearchHandler>
      <SearchHandler Placeholder="Enter search term"/>
   </Shell.SearchHandler>

   <ContentPage.Content>
      <!--Get you desired content here-->
   </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Himanshu Dwivedi, Sorry, your solution is not for my requirements, as I wanted those tabs should also have to hide when the search icon is clicked.